# NetBeans, GlassFish JPA and MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to create a web application in NetBeans using JPA (EclipseLink) and MySQL. When I try to run the application, I get this error in the GlassFish application server.

The glassfish-resources.xml looks fine.

However, I don't see the connection pool mysql_mysql_rootPool under the glassfish server in NetBeans IDE Services/Server.

I am using NetBeans 8.2, GlassFish 4.1.1, MySQL community edition. However I am able to see the database in the NetBeans IDE Services/Database.

Kindly help.

```
Warning: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:99)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:71)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.addSessionToGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:907)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.initSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2671)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:675)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Info: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258
Warning: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/mysql_mysql_rootPool), (applicationName=rest-server) }. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Warning: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/mysql_mysql_rootPool), (applicationName=rest-server) } ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Warning: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]]
Severe: Local Exception Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Error Code: 0
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:750)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:152)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:144)
... 53 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:146)
... 54 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
... 68 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
... 70 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
... 71 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:416)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:128)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:113)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:115)
... 72 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:514)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:321)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:325)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:164)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1342)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:782)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:494)
... 88 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
... 93 more

Severe: Exception while deploying the app [rest-server]
Severe: Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Error Code: 0
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Severe: Exception while deploying the app [rest-server] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
Error Code: 0
Warning:
```

Comment: The error message says: "Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Cannot open file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]"

Comment: How does your JDBC URL look like?

Comment: <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/> in glassfish resources.xml

Comment: <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql" />

Comment: in persistence.xml

Comment: Ah so you don't use the DataSource in Glassfish. Have you searched for mysql_mysql_rootPool

Comment: mysql_mysql_rootPool is defined in glassfish_resources.xml. <jdbc-connection-pool name="mysql_mysql_rootPool" >

Comment: And how does this URL look like?

Comment: <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>